# Email not sending from within Meteor.methods function call

Tags: meteor, email

I am sending an email upon form input from a client. This is how I handle the input on the client side:

```
"submit .class-name": function(event) {
  var text = event.target.text.value;
  Meteor.call('sendEmail', text);
}
```

This is how I set up email and handle the function call on the server side:

```
Meteor.startup(function(){
process.env.MAIL_URL="smtp://email%40gmail.com:password@smtp.gmail.com:465/";
});

Meteor.methods({
  sendEmail: function(text) {
    Email.send({
      from: "meteor.email.2014@gmail.com",
      to: "email@gmail.com",
      subject: "Meteor Can Send Emails via Gmail",
      text: "asdf"//placeholder for now
    });
  }
});
```

EDIT: The issue was with the html form name.

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed that your method is being called? Try adding a console.log('test') call to your method and see if it gets printed out in your meteor bash window when you call the method.